# Reload a frame after a form submit

Tags: html, forms, jsp

I have a situation where I have a `A.jsp`, which has an `<iframe>` with source `B.jsp`.
There is a form in `A.jsp`, which when submitted should ideally reload only the `<iframe>`.
If I do a `response.sendRedirect("B.jsp")`, obviously the entire `A.jsp` page is redirected to `B.jsp`.  I don't want to reload `A.jsp`.
How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the form submit target to the iframe's ID.

```
<form ... target="results">
    ...
</form>

<iframe id="results" ...></iframe>
```

This way the response of the form submit request will end up in that iframe.

---

Needless to say that this is a poor practice whenever both content originate from the same domain. Consider server-side includes like `<jsp:include>`. That's *way* much better for user experience and SEO. If necessary you can always bring in some jQuery to do the asynchronous magic.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. For some reasons I have to avoid <jsp:includes>. I'll try this.

Comment: Thanks. This works. I completely had forgotten about the Target attribute of the form.